# Why does the Akka Streams TestSource not receive every pull as a request?

Tags: scala, scalatest, akka-stream

I am trying to track down a bug in a custom Flow where there were extra requests going upstream. I wrote a test case which should have failed given the behaviour and logging I was seeing but it didn't.

I then made a trivial Flow with an obvious extra pull and yet the test still did not fail.

Here is an example:

```
class EagerFlow extends GraphStage[FlowShape[String, String]] {

  val in: Inlet[String] = Inlet("EagerFlow.in")
  val out: Outlet[String] = Outlet("EagerFlow.out")

  override def shape: FlowShape[String, String] = FlowShape(in, out)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
    setHandler(in, new InHandler {
      override def onPush() = {
        println("EagerFlow.in.onPush")
        println("EagerFlow.out.push")
        push(out, grab(in))
        println("EagerFlow.in.pull")
        pull(in)
      }
    })
    setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
      override def onPull() = {
        println("EagerFlow.out.onPull")
        println("EagerFlow.in.pull")
        pull(in)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Here is a test that should pass, i.e. confirm that there is an extra request.

```
"Eager Flow" should "pull on every push" in {
  val sourceProbe = TestSource.probe[String]
  val sinkProbe = TestSink.probe[String]

  val eagerFlow = Flow.fromGraph(new EagerFlow)

  val (source, sink) = sourceProbe.
    via(eagerFlow).
    toMat(sinkProbe)(Keep.both).
    run

  sink.request(1)
  source.expectRequest()
  source.expectNoMsg()

  source.sendNext("hello")
  sink.expectNext()
  source.expectRequest()
}
```

In standard output you can see:

```
0C3E08A8 PULL DownstreamBoundary -> TestSpec$EagerFlow@1d154180 (TestSpec$EagerFlow$$anon$4$$anon$6@7e62ecbd) [TestSpec$EagerFlow$$anon$4@36904dd4]
EagerFlow.out.onPull
EagerFlow.in.pull
0C3E08A8 PULL TestSpec$EagerFlow@1d154180 -> UpstreamBoundary (BatchingActorInputBoundary(id=0, fill=0/16, completed=false, canceled=false)) [UpstreamBoundary]
EagerFlow.in.onPush
EagerFlow.out.push
EagerFlow.in.pull
0C3E08A8 PULL TestSpec$EagerFlow@1d154180 -> UpstreamBoundary (BatchingActorInputBoundary(id=0, fill=0/16, completed=false, canceled=false)) [UpstreamBoundary]

assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg:
  java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg:
  at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
at akka.testkit.TestKitBase$class.expectMsgPF(TestKit.scala:368)
at akka.testkit.TestKit.expectMsgPF(TestKit.scala:737)
at akka.stream.testkit.StreamTestKit$PublisherProbeSubscription.expectRequest(StreamTestKit.scala:665)
at akka.stream.testkit.TestPublisher$Probe.expectRequest(StreamTestKit.scala:172)
```

(This is with the debug logging in `akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter#processEvent`, well actually using print-points but effectively the same thing)

Why does this pull stop in the `UpstreamBoundary` and never make it back to the `TestSource.probe`?

I have quite a few tests which use `expectNoMsg()` to ensure correct backpressure but it seems these will just give false positives. How should I be testing this if this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your test applicable you'll need to set up your Flow buffer to be of size 1.

```
val settings = ActorMaterializerSettings(system)
  .withInputBuffer(initialSize = 1, maxSize = 1)
implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer(settings)
```

The default sizes are:

```
  # Initial size of buffers used in stream elements
  initial-input-buffer-size = 4
  # Maximum size of buffers used in stream elements
  max-input-buffer-size = 16
```

This means that Akka will eagerly request and ingest up to 16 elements **anyway** at your first request. More info on internal buffers can be found [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.14/scala/stream/stream-rate.html#Internal_buffers_and_their_effect).

Comment: Yes you are right. I can see that `BatchingActorInputBoundary` is calling `tryRequest` for 16 elements. Still seems a little backwards how there is an async boundary being created in the first place. I would have thought the TestKit to provide something that made testing an individual stage a bit more intuitive. The other thing I didn't realise was that `Probe.expectRequest()` permits multiple and returns the number. Would be more obvious if this had a plural name.

Comment: Still a pitfall in 2021. You saved my day!